# Documentation edit is a question

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

I was looking at [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/90707) to the AngularJS documentation, and to me it looks like a question. I rejected the edit, saying it was a question. Should I take any other actions? When I looked at the user's profile who made this edit, I saw that this was his/her first action on SO, ever since the account was created 1 year ago.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You performed the correct action.

I rejected it, as well—you know what they say: give someone a textbox and they will type in it :)

Comment: We need to ban a reviewer....

Comment: I don't understand? Did you mean ban an editor? Or is there someone who's reviewing items incorrectly?

Comment: Someone *approved* the change.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at the history.  Yes, we're going to be looking at how the queue is being processed and add throttles/audits soon.

Comment: @JarrodDixon You definitely should. I approved way too many suggestions and I somewhat feel bad. :)